# Question falsely closed

Tags: support

This question:

https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/13924/making-sure-a-uk-political-party-complies-with-all-aspects-of-the-data-protectio

Is plainly and obviously about processes within the political arena and thus was falsely closed and clearly falls within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: Does the downvote mean someone is capable of questioning the truth of this post, or is it merely a protest downvote?

Comment: The de facto behavior of community moderation on Stack Exchange sites suggests that the specific cases overrule the general guidelines. You can appeal the closure of a question, but basing an appeal on the notion that there are inviolate rules about what should and shouldn't be closed won't be very effective. It's always a judgement call by the community on a case by case basis.

Comment: You might be able to remove your personal context and just ask the question of what vehicles exist and are available to private citizens to ensure that a party complies with the DPA of 1988.  Though that may actually be a better question for Law SE

Comment: @The Master Priest see http://meta.politics.stackexchange.com/questions/2596/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes

Answer (score 6):

The main problem with that question is that you are asking for specific legal advice for your situation.  Specific legal advice is off-topic anywhere on Stack Exchange.  You should go see a solicitor.

A second problem is that you obscure important details.  I follow why you might find that necessary, but that just highlights why you should talk in confidence with a solicitor rather than in public on the internet.

How could anyone advise you without knowing what the hidden information is?  Your question is so generic as to be unanswerable.  At the same time, it is so specific to you that answering it may be illegal.  The only advice that anyone could give legally is to consult a solicitor.

I would agree that if on-topic anywhere, it would be on Politics.SE.  As such the close reason is confusing.  But as specific legal advice, it is not on-topic on Stack Exchange.  The correct answer anywhere is to tell you to hire a solicitor with whom you can discuss the facts of the case without hiding your identity and other relevant details.

Note that your behavior here tends to lend credence to the idea that you are in the wrong there as well.  You are quick to take offense and jump to conclusions.  However, a solicitor with full access to the facts would be in a better position to advise you on this.

**TL;DR**  Consult a solicitor.

Comment: The help center text cited in the closure reason lists all processes within the political arena as on topic. I am a small business person and cannot afford to retain the services of a paid solicitor.

Comment: Do you believe the poor should not be allowed access to justice?

Comment: @TheMasterPriest That's unfortunately how our justice system works. But this is not the place to discuss if we think it's fair that only rich people can afford civil lawsuits in our society. We aren't in the position to change that. We only discuss what content belongs on politics.SE, and Brythan makes very good points why this question won't give you any useful advise.

Comment: @TheMasterPriest At least you can deduct legal costs as a business expense and possibly get a loan against the assets of your business to help with operating expenses like legal fees.